# Reading table from word document and displaying it

Tags: wpf, ms-word, interop

I need to read tables from a Word document and display them in my WPF application. What is the best possible way to do this?

I am using `Word Interop` to read Word files. I am able to get the tables from the Word file using the `Word.Document.Tables` collection. But I am unable to find how to display these tables in my WPF application.

Comment: Do you need to display them as is ? or Do you have some control in your WPF app where to add the text?

Comment: Display as is. Which control can i use?

Comment: I have researched quite a lot on this thing but couldn't find anything!!